# Is there a better way to handle window properties & child components in React/Redux?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-redux

So I have a `<Layout>` component. Based on the page, it loads in different child components. In those, they might have tabs and they might not.

This changes the way I want scrolling to work, and therefore the markup of the scrolling.

I basically ended up making sure each child component had an element like `<div id="scroll-container">`

Then within my `<Layout>` component I did this:

```
componentDidMount() {

  this._updateHeight();
  window.addEventListener('resize', this._updateHeight, false);
},

componentDidUpdate() {
  this._updateHeight();
},

_updateHeight() {
  var container = document.getElementById('scroll-container');

  if (container ) {
    let height = window.innerHeight - container.getBoundingClientRect().top;
    container.style.height = height + 'px';
  }
},
```

I know there are helpers for things like `getBoundintClientRec`, which I am going to use later. Right now I am just wondering about the general flow.

I was thinking I can make a component that is `scroll-container` that wraps wherever I need that, but then I'd need to always do something like

```
<ScrollContainer {...this.props}>
  <ChildIHadThereAnyway>
</ScrollContainer>
```

Meanwhile is a component "supposed" to know about window? `<Layout>` is currently my top level so I think it's fine there, but unsure about children and such.

Basically unsure what is best for connecting global window size with aspect of components position.

Comment: I should note the extra trick is that heights are dynamic based on things after render, which is why I can't just use https://github.com/seatgeek/react-infinite, which seems to do the `<ScrollContainer>` method

Answer (score 0):

This method is not perfect but works fine for me.

My code has root component `Application`, if you're using `react-router` you probably have one too, otherwise it's easy do add it.

I have as well reducer and actions for managing window properties like screen resolution or orientation. Lets call them `windowReducer` and `windowActions`.

In root component I've register event handlers with something like:

```
componentDidMount() {
  window.addEventListener('resize', this.onWindowResolutionChange, false);
}

onWindowResolutionChange() {
  windowActions.onResolutionChange({
    width: window.innerWidth,
    height: window.innerHeight
  });
}
```

As other redux actions `onResolutionChange` dispatches action to `windowReducer` where it sets new window width and height.

So, to get them in your component you can just pass them from container's `state` as other props.

The worst in this approach is the fact that `state` changes too frequently witch leads to extra re-rendering of the components. Usually you're using functions like [debounce](https://lodash.com/docs#debounce) to avoid it. If one of you're component needs immediate changes and other debounced, you will probably end (as I do) with two different actions setting different values to state (`width` and `debouncedWidth`).

Comment: So with this solution you are suggesting the window size is store prop. And then to factor in an element's specific position (ie my `scroll-container`) you would go with the <WrapElement> component which would handle the height of itself based on store dimensions + its own dimensions/position